# Memory of Integer

Tags: java, memory, integer

When I write:
`Integer i = 5;`
`Integer i = new Integer(5);`
Are these two lines equal?
In the memory the type `i` will be allocated in the heap as the same way in those two lines? And if yes, how all of this happens in the memory?

Comment: No. The first will be a reference to an object in the integer cache. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7

Comment: Remark: [`new Integer(int value)` is deprecated since Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)). We should use [`Integer::valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) instead.

Comment: @Turing85 Not only deprecated as you said, but also marked for removal as of Java 16. See [*JEP 390: Warnings for Value-Based Classes*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/390).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are these two lines equal?

No.

The first line is the same as

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(5);
```

The compiler rewrites the code to that, which is known as [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Refer to the [Javadoc for `Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)):

> If a new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Integer(int), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values. This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

So, `Integer.valueOf(5) == Integer.valueOf(5)` (it's the same instance returned each time) whereas `new Integer(5) != new Integer(5)` (a new instance is created each time).

But in all cases - as with all objects in Java - the Integer object is on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68520461/642706) is correct, and should be accepted. I can add a couple more thoughts and a diagram.

## `Integer` constructor to be removed

Be aware that the constructors for all the primitive wrapper classes ( [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html), [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html), [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html), etc.) are not only deprecated, as of Java 16 & 17 they are **marked for eventual removal**. See [*JEP 390: Warnings for Value-Based Classes*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/390).

So, while interesting technically, this Question is moot practically.

## `new` means new

To sum up Turner’s Answer: **`new` means new**. Calling the constructor via `new` always results in a new object being instantiated. This means a bit more memory taken to hold each new object.

## Cache of `Integer` objects

The other two avenues, using a numeric literal or calling [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)), may reuse an existing object cached by the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). Using a [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#Software_caches) conserves [memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory).

Here is a decorated screenshot of a debugger showing the result of calling `toString` on each of these three approaches. We can see that `x` (numeric literal) and `y` (`valueOf` factory method) both point to the same object. Meanwhile, `z` (`new` constructor) points to a different object.

[image: decorated screenshot of three ways to instantiate an Integer object with two being retrieved from a cache.]

---

(The `42` & `7` were added for dramatic effect, to emphasize that the cache is a pool of possibly many objects. This actual code as shown would not have produced those objects.)